# fill a JSON file with embedded arrays from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a simple "rss" (ApplicationRecord) table indexed by an id. I would like to have a structured JSON that group each user from a family in an array structure. And then each family in a global array. How can I do that ?

my current plain code to put my data in a json file is :

```
json.rss @rss do |rs|
  json.id rs.id
  json.name rs.name
  json.family rs.family
  json.lastdate rs.lastdate
  json.last rs.last
  json.s1w rs.s1w
  json.s2w rs.s2w  
end
```

But the target file that I want is this one :

```
{
  "rss": [
              {
              "familyname": "Smith",
              "children": [
                            {
                              "id": "1",
                              "name": "bob",
                              "lastdate": "2010-09-23",
                              "last": "0.88",
                              "s1w": "0.83",
                              "s2w": "0.88"
                            },
                            {
                              "id": 2,
                              "name": "Mary",
                              "lastdate": "2011-09-23",
                              "last": "0.89",
                              "s1w": "0.83",
                              "s2w": "0.87"
                            }
                          ]
              },
              {
              "familyname": "Wesson",
               "children": [
                            {
                              "id": "1",
                              "name": "john",
                              "lastdate": "2001-09-23",
                              "last": "0.88",
                              "s1w": "0.83",
                              "s2w": "0.88"
                            },
                            {
                              "id": 2,
                              "name": "Bruce",
                              "lastdate": "2000-09-23",
                              "last": "0.89",
                              "s1w": "0.83",
                              "s2w": "0.87"
                            }
                           ]
              }      
      ]
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a example of the input and the desired output in the question. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The grouping you are trying to achieve can be done in Ruby with:

```
@rss.group_by(&:family).values
```

This is assuming @rss is an array-like collection of objects that have a `.family` method. The result: is an array of arrays of objects grouped by family.

Now it will be up to use to use Jbuilder's `array!` method to build the desired JSON output.

Comment: I am quite new to this subject. Can you develop a little please ?

Comment: Have you tried the line I gave you? You need to give us more information about your @rss object and what it contains.

Comment: I finally I modify my model by spliting it in two.

Comment: Please modify the question if it still applies to the your new setup.